# Water in basement plug install

Tags: civil-engineering

I have a basement which floods, the water comes through a drain in the floor. I am therefore looking to use an [HFT Pipestoppers](https://www.huntingdonfusion.com/index.php/en/products-list/101-mechanical-pipe-plugs-and-stoppers/steel-plugs/683-ordering-steel) to stop the water coming in

I think the water comes from an old tank (B) (which I can't find).

Does anyone know what pressure I would expect in the pipe to the basement (x)
and advise if this is a good option.

[image: ]]

Answer (score 2):

The pressure will be:

$$P = \text{density} \times \text{gravity} \times \text{height}$$

Density is 1000 kg/m<sup>3</sup>, and gravity is 9.81 m/s<sup>2</sup>

But your problem is defining the height above the measuring point as you say you don’t know where the tank is.

Comment: I could guess the bottom of the basement to the top of the tank would be 2.5m max

Comment: Then plug the numbers in, h is in meters and pressure in Pascals

Comment: thanks Solar,Looks like the pressure would be 0.2 bar and those plugs are good to 2 bar